# to make audio from parts of many other audios

Tags: cocoa, touch

I want to create an audio file from small audios.
This other audio files should include selected ranges from other audios.
For example, from the 1st audio from 10th sec to 50th sec and from the 2nd audio from 20th sec to 30th sec.
Then I want to create a 3rd audio file which will be 50 sec.

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain your development project a bit better for us to help you here.  What are you trying to develop?  What platform?

Comment: I am jet doing project to mix audios. Just want to create an audio file from many others. In resulting file parts of audios wil be tr. Some what like Movie Maker in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with videos, and the audio process should be similar.  You will need to make an `AVMutableComposition`, which will need to contain one or multiple (if you want to cross-fade) `AVAssetTrack`s to which you will assign `AVAsset`s that use your source audio.  You will also need to create an `AVMutableAudioMix` for the composition to specify volumes and fades.

Comment: Ok. I got what to do. But not following how this AVMutableComposition, AVAssetTrack, AVAsset, AVMutableAudioMix work. Can you please give example to tale 1 composition and add two audio files and make complete track. Even I want to export it and save.

Comment: It's not a simple process, but check out this question and the link to an Apple sample, which you can adapt to use audio instead of video: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830932/cross-fade-within-avmutablevideocomposition